# Big Theta Run Time on Double Nested For

Tags: runtime, big-o

I'm trying to nail down a Big Theta run time on a double nested for loop that's a little fancier than your regular Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) double loop.

```
for i=0..n do
    for j=0..i do
        // some O(1) work
    end
end
```

I know that I can say it's O(n<sup>2</sup>), but I'd like it in Θ-format.

Answer (score 1):

The number of steps in two nested loops:

```
1 + 2 + ... + (n+1) = (n+1)*(n+2)/2
```

To prove that running time is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), you need to find three constants `c1`, `c2` and `n0` so that:

> c1 * n<sup>2</sup> <= (n+1)*(n+2)/2 <= c2 * n<sup>2</sup>

for all `n >= n0`.

Since you know the specific task to do now, here is my hint:

*`c1` and `c2` could be chosen as `1/2` and `1` respectively, find an appropriate `n0`*.

Comment: Which evaluates to (n^2 + 3n + 2)/2, so I can call this Θ(n^2)?

Comment: Informally yes. But this intends to be a proof, so you have to show it formally.